# How can I get the memory address of a Flutter / Dart variable? Is this possible?

Tags: flutter, dart, memory

I would like to print the current memory address of a variable in Dart but I don't know if this is possible. I want to write a code to show all memory address in a liked list structure.

Advice are welcome.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's not possible to access raw memory of Dart objects. Dart is a garbage collected language which means that Dart objects are not guaranteed to live at a particular memory address as the garbage collector can (and *certainly will*) move these objects to different memory locations during a garbage collection. Within the Dart virtual machine Dart objects are almost exclusively accessed and passed around via handles and not raw pointers for this very reason.

Comment: Thank you Ben, this was useful for me. I will try another solution.

Answer (score 11):

There is no way to print the memory address of a variable in Dart.

Even if you could print the memory address, there is nothing meaningful that you could do with it.

If you want to identify objects, you could use [`identityHashCode`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.5.1/dart-core/identityHashCode.html).

Comment: But is it possible to find that address? Debugging, for example?

Comment: @IvánYoed No, it's not possible.  And even if you're debugging, I have a hard time imagining what you would do with that information.  If you have a debugger attached, you can inspect the objects directly.  If you don't have a debugger attached, then there's nothing you could do with the address anyway.

Comment: There are many cases in constrained systems where you want to see the actual memory dump. Never say never. There is a reason people are asking for this.

Comment: @RichieHH While it's not the answer you want to hear, the fact remains: you can't do it.  If you could programmatically obtain the address of the underlying object, you also could just programmatically inspect that object instead.  Furthermore, even if you could get the address, unless your memory dump is from that exact same moment, there'd be no guarantee that the object remained at that address.  Finally, for the scenario you describe, asking how to obtain the memory address of an object is an X-Y problem; you instead should be asking how to analyze a memory dump from a Dart process.

Comment: In Go you can, wish Dart able

Comment: Go and Dart are Completely different languages.

Comment: If you transpile Dart to JavaScript, there won't even *be* a memory address. You would have to see what the JavaScript compiler did with *its* code (mabye WebAssembly?) and inspect the memory of whatever VM or actual machine is running *that*.